# What does "-n" means in the command

Tags: shell, command, ksh

Can someone tell me what does "-n" means?
Thank you in advance!
`script_name.ksh –p file_name.txt –n Some Name`

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/Bookshelf/Computers/shells.shtml

Answer (score 1):

`-n` is a parameter which is interpreted by `script_name.ksh`. You need to read the documentation of `script_name.ksh` to know how it interprets `-n`.